# HTML DOM Parse and Character encoding on XMLHTTPRequest at Firefox extension

Tags: character-encoding, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest, html-parsing, gecko

I am now writing firefox 4 bootstrapped extension.

---

The following is my story:

When I'm using **@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1, nsIXMLHttpRequest**, content of target URL can be successfully loaded by req.responseText.

I parsed the responseText to DOM by createElement method and innerHTML property into a BODY Element.

Everything seems to be successful.

However, there is a problem on character encoding ( charset ).

As I need the extension detect the charset of target documents, **overriding** the Mine type of request with text/html; charset=blahblah.. seems not to meet my need.

I've tried the **@mozilla.org/intl/utf8converterservice;1, nsIUTF8ConverterService**, but it seems that XMLHTTPRequest has no ScriptableInputStream or even any InputStream or readable stream.

I have no idea on reading a target document content in a suitable, **automatically detected** charset, no matter the function of Auto-Detect Character Encoding in GUI or the charset readed at head meta tag of the content document.

---

**EDIT:** Would it be practical if I parse whole document including HTML, HEAD, BODY tag to a DOM object, but without loading extensive document like js, css, ico files?

**EDIT:** Method on the article at MDC titled as "**HTML to DOM**" which is using **@mozilla.org/feed-unescapehtml;1, nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML** is **inappropriate** as it parsed with lots of **error** and **mistake** with **baseURI** can not be **set** in type of **text/html**. All attribute HREF in A Elements are **missed** when it contains a **relative path**.

**EDIT#2:** It would still be nice if there are any methods that can convert the incoming responseText into readable UTF-8 charset strings. :-)

---

Any ideas or works to solve encoding problem are appreciated. **:-)**

**PS.** the target documents are **universal** so there are **no specific charset** ( or ... **preknown** ), and of course not only UTF8 as it has already defined in default.

---

**SUPP:**

Til now, I have two brief main ideas of solving this problem.

Can anybody could help me to work out of the XPCOM modules and methods' names?

---

To **Specify** the charset while parsing Content into DOM.

We need to first know the charset of the document ( by extracting head meta Tag, or header).
Then,

- find out a method that can specify the charset when parsing body content.
- find out a method that can parse both head and body.

---

To **Convert** or **Make** Incoming responseText into/be UTF-8 so parsing to DOM Element with default charset UTF-8 is still working.

X seems to be not practical and sensible : Overiding the Mine type with charset is an implementation of this idea but we can not preknow the charset before initiating a request.

Comment: Is the charset UTF-8 or really blahblahblah?

Comment: All charset that Firefox can recognize, as default charset firefox used in XHR is UTF-8 but there still lots of website using charset besides UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are no more other answer.

After a day of tests, I've found out that there is a way (although it is clumsy) to solve my problem.

`xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');` , where xhr stand for XMLHttpRequest Handler.

> To force Firefox to treat it as plain
>   text, using a user-defined character
>   set.  This tells Firefox not to parse
>   it, and to let the bytes pass through
>   unprocessed.
>
> Refers to [MDC Document: Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data)

And then use **Scriptable Unicode Converter** : **@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter, nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter**

Variable `charset` can be extracted from head meta tags no matter by **regexp** from `req.responseText` (with unknown charset) or something other method.

```
var unicodeConverter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
unicodeConverter.charset = charset;
str = unicodeConverter.ConvertToUnicode(str);
```

An unicode string, as well as a family of UTF-8, is finally produced. :-)

Then simply parse to `body` element and meet my need.

Other brilliant ideas are still welcome. Feel free to object my answer by sufficient reason. :-)